# Is there a list of non-Hebrew words and names in the Torah?

Tags: torah-study, language

Not all words in the Torah are in Hebrew. A famous example is Lavan calling the Gal-Ed "[Yigar Sahadutah](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Genesis.31.47?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi&aliyot=0)" which is the Aramaic version of Gal-Ed. Another example is what the [gemara](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Sanhedrin.4b.13?vhe=Wikisource_Talmud_Bavli&lang=bi) says about the word "Totafot" (setting aside the [possibility](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/90057/20472) that this is a pre-Bavel term<sup>1</sup>):

> Rabbi Akiva says: There is no need for this proof, as the requirement of four compartments can be derived from the word totafot itself: The word tat in the language of the Katfei means two, and the word pat in the language of Afriki also means two, and therefore totafot can be understood as a compound word meaning: Four.

I was wondering if there was a list of all non-Hebrew words in the Torah (along with, possibly, their meanings)?

---

<sup>1</sup>R' Ahron Marcus in Barzilai, while holding that many non-Hebraic words were derived from the early proto-Hebrew, still held that tat and pat weren't in Hebrew, as well as other words, such as Sha'atnez.

Comment: The premise behind this question is debatable. Some use the first two examples as a proof that Aramaic has the halachic status of a Hebrew.dialect. The Ramban says that the proof from "Totafot" is proof that the words have such meaning in Hebrew and other languages.