# Non-Hebrew words in the Torah?

Tags: translation

The Torah says, about the commandment on tefillin:

> וּקְשַׁרְתָּ֥ם לְא֖וֹת עַל־יָדֶ֑ךָ וְהָי֥וּ לְטֹטָפֹ֖ת בֵּ֥ין עֵינֶֽיךָ׃ -- And you shall bind them as a sign upon your hand and they shall be for frontlets between your eyes. [Deuteronomy 6:8]

In the Talmud, Rabbi Akiva explains that the word טֹטָפֹ֖ת -- *totafot* is extracted from two other languages and means that the tefillin must have four compartments:

> The word tat in the Kapti language means two, and the word pat in the Afriki language also means two, [so totafot is a compound word meaning “four”]. [Sanhedrin 4b, Menachot 34b]

Why would the Torah contain non-Hebrew words?  If some Hebrew words originate from other languages, then they are still considered Hebrew words.  Why would Rabbi Akiva remind us of their etymology?

I know "the Torah speaks the language of men", that the Book of Daniel was written in Aramaic, and that the Talmud includes many Greek words (“Sanhedrin” is a Greek word meaning “assembly”).  But this is the Torah -- it's supposed to be only in lashon hakodesh.  The only other place where the Torah uses a foreign word, it quickly translates it:

> וַיִּקְרָא־ל֣וֹ לָבָ֔ן יְגַ֖ר שָׂהֲדוּתָ֑א וְיַֽעֲקֹ֔ב קָ֥רָא ל֖וֹ גַּלְעֵֽד -- Laban named it Yegar-sahadutha [Aramaic], but Jacob named it Gal-ed [Hebrew]. [Genesis 31:47]

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/116876/is-there-a-list-of-non-hebrew-words-and-names-in-the-torah?r=SearchResults

Comment: "this is the Torah -- it's supposed to be only in lashon hakodesh" can you provide a source for this? Another place the Torah mentions an Aramaic word is in Devarim where it says that at mount sinai Hashem came with his holy multitudes {of angels}, it says "viasa mirivivos kodesh", the word "viasa", he came, is aramaic, and there it doesn't translate it back to hebrew

Comment: @ravchaimhaqoton wrote a great book on the topic: https://www.amazon.com/Lashon-HaKodesh-History-Holiness-English/dp/1937887367